# Xcode errors don't show up in the numbered column on left

Tags: c++, xcode

I am brand new to any type of programming and I'm trying to create a program right now. It has errors in it, and usually on the left side of Xcode, where you can click on lines to make breakpoints, it shows a little red exclamation point on any line with an error or warning. For some reason, my Xcode is only showing the errors on the far left past the breakpoint column.

[image]

I am sorry for my terrible lingo. Hopefully I am explaining this well enough. Yet there are no exclamation points in the code itself. When I click on the error under the far far left window, it pulls a window over my code that talks all about the errors but doesn't show me where it is.

[image]

I have the feeling this is an easy fix and I just did something stupid, but how do I make it so that I can see the errors on that left column again with the breakpoints? It would make my job so much easier. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XCode -> Preferences -> General

Check the box marked "Show live issues"

[image]